# React SPA inside specific ASPNET Core Project route

Tags: reactjs, facebook, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

Just wondering if anybody has done this.

What I'm looking for is a full React app with access to API Controllers **inside** an ASP Core app that uses a layout and Identity, etc.

My reason is that I need Facebook login using .NET Cores Facebook Identity. If I was to separate the front end from the back end completely, when Facebook is authenticating the user, there is no connection between the front end and the route Facebook returns to after authentication is successful. E.G `/signin-Facebook` or `/Account-ExternalLogin`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I sincerly doubt your solution is the simpliest / most eficient, here's a link on how to implement this in WebAPI with Angular, but workflow is the same: https://fullstackmark.com/post/13/jwt-authentication-with-aspnet-core-2-web-api-angular-5-net-core-identity-and-facebook-login

Comment: Ah I never thought (or knew how) of using post messages. Great link to the article. Got it working with React now and its pretty good! If you write up an answer with that link, I will accept it :-)

Comment: Also, thanks for posting this. I didnt think I would find a way!

Comment: Since it's a link only answer, I won't post it. Glad it helped you! :)